# Increase in percentage of FALSE responses for HERE REST API reverse geocoder

Tags: php, here-api

I have a CGI PHP 5.4 process that runs continuously on Ubuntu server 12.04.  I use free HERE maps REST API for reverse geocoding:
    $myresult=file_get_contents('http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox='.$latitude.','.$longitude.',100&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=6&app_id=MyAppIdGoesHere&app_code=MyAppCodeGoesHere');

The amount of FALSE responses I am receiving has increased significantly in the past 2 days.  Prior to yesterday, FALSE responses average less than 1%.  This is true for the data I reviewed going back 6 weeks.  Yesterday and today, FALSE responses are occurring for approximately 10% of requests.

I have confirmed the coordinates being submitted are valid - I have manually submitted a portion of them via Chrome browser and received normal address information in the response.

I understand for free use of the HERE API's the maximum requests are 100,000 per month.  I am not exceeding or approaching this limit.

Is there a frequency limitation on requests?  Is there perhaps a timeout happening on the HERE server?

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Aha! in linux errorlog:  HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity.  So... with a bit more digging.... you know.    Anybody from HERE technical team out there?  Stack Overflow is the suggested way to get support for free product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CIT, the test environment: reverse.geocoder.**cit**.api.here.com

Use production and you should be fine. Do do so simply remove "cit" from the URL, i.e. http://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/

Comment: Thanks Philip.  You are right.  To elaborate, the .prd has RPS limits for calls based on number of assets licensed.

Comment: @philip  I use production env but I get false response when I hit api with the lat,lon (32.450281, 31.557611 this value is valid) as `https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id="appid"&prox=32.450281,31.557611,200&mode=retrieveAddresses&gen=9` Do you know the reason?